# Is this custom syntax highlighting from Atom package possible with VS Code in any and all languages?

Tags: visual-studio-code, comments, atom-editor, syntax-highlighting

This comment syntax highlighting from [this package](https://atom.io/packages/todo-show) is very nice for making different comments stick out & organizing thoughts.

It looks like the picture below...

Is this possible in VS Code for any and all languages?

Requirement is that this should be possible to integrate with existing themes in VS Code.

Minimally I'm asking for Dart/Flutter, but would prefer a universal comment syntax highlighter so all languages get same comment treatment.

[image: Atom custom syntax highlighting from package]

Comment: see extension `HighLight`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TODO Highlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wayou.vscode-todo-highlight) Extension does this.